# Windows 2012 DNS does not answer queries about zone itself (SOA, NS, A, ...)

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

I have several Windows servers with DNS and AD roles, some are Win2003, some are Win2012.
There is an AD-integrated zone `example.com` that contains an ip 192.0.2.1 for `example.com` and an ip 203.0.113.1 for `bar.example.com`.

- A DNS query for `bar.example.com` returns the ip 203.0.113.1 as expected, no matter which server is asked. (Especially, we can be confident that replication has completed)
- A DNS query for `example.com` asking any of the Win2003 servers returns the ip 192.0.2.1 as expected
- A DNS query for `example.com` asking any of the Win2012 servers returns "Host not found"
- A DNS query for SOA or NS records of zone `example.com` asking any of the Win2003 servers returns the correct information
- The same query  asking any of the Win2012 servers returns "Host not found"

I also tried to turn the zone into a non-AD-integrated one that is only served form the old servers. I hoped that the Win2012 servers would then return the correct answer per forwarding. But this didn't work out either ...

Meanwhile I noticed that I have another zone that has practically the same structure - and there the problem does not occur! I went through all properties of both zones - the only a differences are between SOA serial numbers and the MinTTL settings.

What is going wrong here?

*Edit:* Forgot to mention: In DNS Manager on the problematic servers, all records show up - it is just that they are not returned to DNS queries.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the zone `foo` (or `example.com` as someone later edited) was really `wpad`. Therefore I needed to remove `wpad` from the [globale DNS block list](http://www.mpking.com/2010/02/wpad-does-not-resolve-in-dns.html) applied.